# Show the result of a route in blade view (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I have a route that return an image, and i want the show the result of this route in a blade view, is there a way to directly call controller action or result of this route directly in the blade view ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by giving the URL in src attribute of `<img>` tag as:

```
<img src="{{ route('image.url') }}">
```

Comment: No, the action don't return the url of the image, it returns the image it self (using the library Intervention Image).

Comment: public function image(){
        return $img = Image::make('image.jpg')
            ->resize(800, 500)
            ->insert('sub_image.jpg', 'bottom-right', 10, 10)
            ->response();
}

Comment: When you open that route in a web browser then does it show you the image?

Comment: Yes, it shows the image perfectly (with the modifications I want).

Comment: Have you tried the above solution? Your route is acting as an image itself so, I think it should work.

Comment: Thinks, it works now ... previously I was trying to call the controller action directly in the view and not the route.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You rather don't want to return image in blade. You should create separate controller action, that will return this image and link image src to this route, for example in controller:

```
public function image()
{ 
    return $img = Image::make('image.jpg')->resize(800, 500)
    ->insert('sub_image.jpg', 'bottom-right', 10, 10) ->response(); 
}
```

then you create route to this controller action:

```
Route::get('my-image', 'MyController@image')->name('get-my-image');
```

and then in your Blade view you should link image src to this action:

```
<img src="{{ route('get-my-image') }}">
```

Comment: Think you a lot for this helpful explanation ... problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Well if it's an image, why don't you use an `img` tag?

`<img src="{{ route('my.image') }}" alt="My Image">`

Comment: No, the action don't return the url of the image, it returns the image it self (using the library Intervention Image). This is an example :

Comment: public function image(){ return $img = Image::make('image.jpg') ->resize(800, 500) ->insert('sub_image.jpg', 'bottom-right', 10, 10) ->response(); }

Comment: Think you a lot for this helpful explanation ... problem solved :)